# What are the possible orders of rational functions under composition (with coefficients in the reals)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rational-functions, monoid

Let M be the monoid of rational functions under composition.  What are the possible orders of elements of M?  $1$ is possible using the function $x$. $2$ is possible using the function $-x$. $3$ is possible using $\frac{-1}{1+x}$. $\infty$ is possible using the function $1+x$. Are there any other possible orders of elements?

Comment: Is that a group?  What's the inverse of a constant function?  What's the inverse of $x\mapsto x^5+x+1$?

Comment: Did you possibly intend to ask about Mobius transformations, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158442/finite-groups-of-functions-under-function-composition)?

Comment: @lulu I fixed it and now it says "monoid"

Comment: Well, I expect you meant to ask about Mobius transformations, and that's covered pretty thoroughly in the question I linked to.

Comment: I'm asking about any rational function, not just Mobius transformations.

Comment: But of course the only invertible (in your sense) rational functions are the Mobius transformations, that's the point.  As is spelled out in the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: What's the proof?

Comment: the one spelled out in that duplicate.  Please study it.

Comment: My question is only about the reals, but the coefficients can be anything in the reals.

Comment: Restricting to the reals gives you *fewer* functions to work with, not more.

Comment: The question linked asks about integer coefficients, not reals.